# how to access process.env.endPointAPI in factories

Tags: angularjs, api, heroku, yeoman

how to access this variable "process.env.endPointAPI"  in yeoman

in the factories Services ?

I want to call the API from different server?

Comment: It is necessary more info regarding your code. I guess you are using a yeoman generator with nodejs server side, maybe with expressjs. If that is the case then you need to pass `process.env.endPointAPI` via express or change your grunt/gulp tasks to include it in a custom angular factory when you serve/build your app

Comment: yes its the case , can you describe more how to solve it ? how to pass it ?

Answer (score 1):

*To complement my comment to the question and to provide a more detailed answer:*

It is necessary more info regarding your code. I guess you are using a yeoman generator with nodejs server side, maybe with expressjs. If that is the case then you need to pass process.env.endPointAPI via express with the help of your templating engine or change your grunt/gulp tasks to include it in a custom angular factory (for example) when you serve/build your app.

This [article](http://www.mircozeiss.com/how-to-pass-javascript-variables-from-a-server-to-angular/) describes some of these situations step-by-step.

If the options in the article above don't work for you for some reason, and you are using grunt, maybe you can give [grunt-ng-constant](https://github.com/werk85/grunt-ng-constant) a try. Basically, it will generate you a custom constant-value utility for Angular. Once injected in your app module you can access those values from your controllers for example.